# Throttle not working when calling class method from inside throttled function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, lodash, throttling

I have this code that is throttling text input, but I also want it to throttle a method call which seems to be stopping the text throttling from working.

```js
import { throttle } from 'lodash';
...
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e): void => throttledTextInput(e.target.value)}
        style={{ outline: 'none' }}
      />
...
  const throttledTextInput = throttle((text) => handleThrottledText(text), 1000);
...
  const handleThrottledText = (text: string): void => {
    console.log(text); // without the below two lines it works fine
    const textInputMessage: Array<Action> = [];
    // but when calling the below, the throttling stops working and it 
  };
```

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: Is this in a functional component?

Comment: @Dominic Yes it is

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is in a functional component so that `throttledTextInput` is being created every time you re-render the component, breaking the behaviour of it. I'm guessing that `messagingController.dispatchActions` causes a re-render of your component.

```
const throttledTextInput = useRef(throttle(handleThrottledText, 1000));

const handleThrottledText = (text: string): void => {
  console.log(text);
};
```

`useRef` will create the throttled function only once, you can use the same pattern for debouncing etc.

Call it like this: `throttledTextInput.current('calling throttled func with this text')`.

**If your throttled function has dependencies** they will need to be declared so that the function gets re-created if they change. But be careful, if the throttled callback itself changes the dependencies it will break as the function will keep getting re-created. For this **useCallback** is a more suitable hook:

```
const throttledTextInput = useCallback(
  throttle(text => {
    console.log('called throttle with', text, props.dispatchMessages);
  }, 1000),
  [props.dispatchMessages]
);
```

Unlike `useRef` you call it just with `throttledTextInput('some text')`.

Comment: Thanks! This is great and fixes the throttling, but it breaks another part of my app - it seems now it will not react to prop changes or that the parent will not set state that is passed as a prop to this component..

Comment: Thanks very much, unfortunately using `useCallback` has the same effect as using no hook at all where the throttle stops working. I think this is because I have the get `useCallback` to 'listen` to a function that's passed in to `messagingController.dispatchActions` as a parameter.

Comment: I have updated my code above to show what I'm trying to do with `useCallback`

Comment: It will be easier to put your `handleThrottledText ` code inside of useCallback, otherwise since you are passing it as dependency and it is created every render, the useCallback function also is and so throttle won't work

Comment: Thanks very much @Dominic - I've now added update 2 to the post - would it be possible for you to be a little bit more explicit when you say put the `handleThrottledText code inside of useCallback', as I've done when I think you're suggesting and the function is now not even being called. I'm desperate to get this working so really appreciate it! :)

Comment: It looks like you started currying the function twice `(text) => (): void => {` See https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-poincare-1g9cd

Comment: Thanks, have made my final update above - I think I know what you meant earlier about putting the 'handleThrottledText` function in `useCallback`. It seems like I can get throttle to work but whatever I put in the `useCallback` array parameter for `handleThrottledText` it either doesn't work at all or I lose the throttle :(

Comment: That's because `handleThrottledTextResponse` is created every render so the depedency changes and so the throttle callback is recreated, you need to wrap that one in a callback or ref too... joys of hooks! `const handleThrottledTextResponse = useCallback(() => {...}, [setTextInputResponses])`

Comment: Thanks very much, I wish it worked but it doesn't 